# WiX burn bootstrapping run different InstallCommand parameter for silent install

Tags: wix, nsis, chain, silent-installer

I have a Wix installer which needs to use a bootstrapper. I have included an extract of the `Bundle.wxs` below. It shows the `Chain`, which is to first install `.Net 4.5.2` and then depending upon whether the installer has been called with -s for silent install calls `ExePackage` with or without the `InstallCommand` with a value of `/S`. The "**OtherInstaller**" is a NSIS (nulscript installer) installer so requires a case sensitive `/S` to trigger it's silent install. I understand that `UILevel=2` is the condition to check for for a silent install, but for some reason "OtherInstaller" is not getting called with the `/S` silent argument. Then after that the "**MainMsiInstaller**" is called.

```
<Chain>      
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Web"/>      

  <ExePackage Id="OtherInstallerLoud" 
              SourceFile="..\..\bootstrapper\OtherInstallerFile" 
              InstallCondition="NOT UILevel=2"/>

  <ExePackage Id="OtherInstallerSilent"
              SourceFile="..\..\bootstrapper\\OtherInstallerFile"
              InstallCommand="/S "
              InstallCondition="UILevel=2"/>

  <MsiPackage Id="MainMsiInstaller" 
              DisplayInternalUI="yes" 
              SourceFile="..\..\bin\$(var.CandleCfgName)\MainMsiInstaller.msi" />
</Chain>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the end a solution that worked for me (whether the best solution, or not) was to ensure that the version of `burn.exe` I was using was `3.11.xxxx` and `InstallCondition="WixBundleUILevel=2"` which is a WIX variable which is available in `v3.11` upwards.

So in essence...

```
<Chain>      
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Web"/>      

  <ExePackage Id="OtherInstallerLoud" 
              SourceFile="..\..\bootstrapper\OtherInstallerFile" 
              InstallCondition="NOT WixBundleUILevel=2"/>

  <ExePackage Id="OtherInstallerSilent"
              SourceFile="..\..\bootstrapper\OtherInstallerFile"
              InstallCommand="/S "
              InstallCondition="WixBundleUILevel=2"/>

  <MsiPackage Id="MainMsiInstaller" 
              DisplayInternalUI="no" 
              SourceFile="..\..\bin\$(var.CandleCfgName)\MainMsiInstaller.msi" />
</Chain>
```

Comment: what happens when you run the bootstrapper is called in UI mode, doesn't it skip the NSIS install?

Comment: @Pavan - Thank you for your response, but I have not looked at this for over three years and cannot even remember the project, let alone the context of the question now! Working on entirely different projects.